# How to show/hide div box based on radioList change in Yii2?

Tags: yii2

I would like to display a div box according to the selection of a radio list using Yii.

I have:

```
<div>
    <p>Servizio aggiuntivo?</p>
    <?php 
        echo Html::radioList('templates', null, $items = ['Si' => 'Si', 'No' => 'No'], $options = 
        ['encode' => false, 'itemOptions' => ['class' =>'radio-inline', 'id' => 'radio']]);
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: The div box has id="yes_box"

Comment: Please take your time and properly format your question, see the guide on [Asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: I've submitted an edit, should be as easy as accepting it.

Comment: Also, is this question specifically after a page/form submit or when you change the radio it displays instantly? Because if it's the latter you should use JavaScript to check for the change and display the div.

Comment: Dillan when I change the radio it displays instantly. How it is possible with js?

Comment: @AngeloDeGiacomo can you please accept the edit to the question so people can read it more easily?

Comment: @DillanWilding Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using jQuery:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("input[name='templates']").change(function() {
        $("#yes_box").show();
    }); 
});
</script>
```

If you aren't:

```
<script>
document.getElementsByName("templates")[0].addEventListener("change", function() {
    document.getElementById("yes_box").style.visibility = "visible";
});
</script>
```

Note: This code is untested so it may require a little tinkering.